# PostgreSQL + debian 9 or MS SQL 2017 enterprise + debian 8 to be able to integrate with MS SQL Server 2017 on Windows Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, debian, integration

I already have MS SQL Server 2017 enterprise on Windows Server 2012-R2 and need to integrate it with other database on linux server (preferably debian).
I also heard that installing MS SQL Server on debian stretch is not a good idea, but it works with debian jessie.

Is it better to use PostgreSQL (or MySQL, or any other open source db) on new stable debian stretch and have to integrate two different databases or downgrade to debian jessie, but use the same version of MS SQL Server on both servers? Or maybe try to install MS SQL Server on debian stretch?

How these options affect on stability, security, performance?

Thank you!

Comment: I run several PostgreSQL instances on both Debian 8 a 9, but MS SQL on Ubuntu 16 and it is stable. Could you please specify what exactly you mean by "integrating" those databases? We transfer data between PG, MS SQL, MySQL, Bigquery, Google Spanner using golang programs but every database has its own specific tasks...

Comment: @JosMac I have to transfer data from the database on new server to MS SQL Server on Windows Server.

Comment: So from PG to MS or MS to MS? Do you need continuous replication or some batched processed snapshots?

Comment: @JosMac I've decided to go with Postgre + debian 9 to MS + windows server. I need to transfer some data (not replicating whole database) once a day. The first thought is just dumping new data from postgres and trying to insert it into MS.